# Redirect subdirectories to root without changing URL

Tags: javascript, html, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Let's say I have the domain www.example.com where my main site files live. For tracking purposes I have various vanity urls like www.example.com/blah, or www.example.com/blue, www.example.com/bleh where blue, blah and bleh are just empty folders/subdirectories of www.example.com.

I'm currently using a meta tag to redirect back to www.example.com(root) but this loses the original URL with the subdirectory attached.

How can I redirect without losing the URL?

In reality, these vanity urls will look more like: www.example.com/bleh?id=1232 and it's important to have that parameter show up in the URL as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can create unique html pages in each of the sub domains, you could hardcode the url in the tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.example.com?param=bleh">
```

If you want to use 1 file and dynamically build the meta redirect with URL, you can put the current window location into the redirect url's params with javascript. Add the following tag at the bottom of your body tag:

```
<script>
  var metaTag = document.createElement('meta');
      metaTag.httpEquiv = "refresh";
      metaTag.content = "0; url=http://www.example.com?param="+encodeURI(window.location.href);
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
</script>
```

Comment: Happy to help. If it answers the questions please mark as answered ;) cheers